# MKL pardiso on Intel Parallel studio Fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl, intel-parallel-studio, pardiso

Trying to make work MKL_Pardiso on MacOS. I installed Intell Parallel Studio and compile program with fort.

```
 include 'mkl.fi'
 INCLUDE 'mkl_pardiso.f90'
 program temp
       use mkl_pardiso   
 end program temp
```

Here is my code to compilier

```
ifort -mkl temp.f90
```

The output is

```
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.1.216/mac/mkl/include/mkl_pardiso.f90(26): error #6218: This statement is positioned incorrectly and/or has syntax errors.
      MODULE MKL_PARDISO_PRIVATE
```

Why does this happen? should I use another flags?

Comment: Fortran is very particular about the sequencing of statements in programs, things like all declarations precede any executables, and a variety of other constraints too.  A blind guess is that the `include` statements, which essentially copy the source in those files into the file being compiled, break those rules. Perhaps at line 26 of `mkl_pardiso.f90`.  Or that line contains a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

please try build as follows: ifort -mkl mkl_pardiso.f90 temp.f90

Comment: This might be a good idea, but should also advise OP to remove `INCLUDE 'mkl_pardiso.f90'` from the code.  Including it *and* compiling it separately will lead to madness and despair.